# Mockito verify method is called ignoring parameter

Tags: mockito

I have a DAO method I want to verify is called inside Service

```
send(User user, Properties prop)
```

I can verify using a protected method in service, but I think it should be private

```
verify(dao).send(user, service.getProp())
```

I tried in different ways to define accepting any properties as:

```
verify(dao).send(user, any(Properties.class)); // or any()

verify(dao).send(user, Matchers.isA(Properties.class)));
```

But all failed with invalid arguments

```
FAILED: testService
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.package.TestService.testService(TestService.java:330)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the exception details explain, you're not allowed to mix raw values (`user`) with matchers (`any(...)`).

Instead, use matchers for all arguments using the `eq(...)` matcher:

```
verify(dao).send(eq(user), any());
```

Comment: It's working, there's a way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Not that I know of, but in any case that's not a limitation, that's simply the API.

Comment: This issue can be solved for the most cases by mockito. You can vote for it here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1398